# Why won't my directive interpolate its scope variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I tried to write a directive to replace a CSS link with an embedded style definition.

[Here is a working version.](http://plnkr.co/edit/pwyedGgNbdUDKbtCXkDJ?p=preview)

Now, I would like to achieve that functionality with interpolation, so I do not have to set the innerHtml of the style element. Unfortunately, that seems to be impossible. I can attach the CSS to the scope, but Angular will not interpolate the code.

[Here is the offending version:](http://plnkr.co/edit/aLZbUhVAFcOLe3uqVkIb?p=preview)

```
.directive('link', function(CssSvc) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    template: '<style type="text/css">{{css}}</style>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.$watch(function() { return CssSvc.css }, function() {
        scope.css = CssSvc.css;
      })
    }

  }
})
```

Can someone explain why this will not work, and if there is a way to make Angular perform the interpolation?

Comment: it 's very interesting question,i will research late,but for now you need to `$watch` variable which located in outter isolated scope and which pass by attribute `ng-model`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the version of Angular I used.

[This one, using version 1.3rc2, works just fine.](http://plnkr.co/edit/HwgbgnRbqWdK4k2uJ7bl?p=preview)

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-rc2" data-semver="1.3.0-rc2" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>\
```

Thanks to reddit user [CureEgg](http://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/2j4r4r/trying_to_find_what_change_from_12_to_13_is/cl9jphs), I now know that **[this was fixed as a bug in 1.3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#bug-fixes-37)**.

Comment: Yeah, I'd avoid release candidates as they are usually a bit buggy